# Функция с переменным количеством аргументов работает некорректно

Tags: c

Почему данный код работает некорректно (выдает рандомные числа из памяти) ?

```
#include <stdio.h>


int fun(int n, ... ){
    int *ptr = &n;
    ptr++;

    return *ptr;
}


int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", fun(1, 10));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Естественно. Кто учил вас так работать с varargs?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev интернет, чтоб его...

Comment: Возьмите лучше учебник, он точно не обманет. Или используйте официальную документацию и стандарты. А к источникам в интернете надо подходить с осторожностью.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Не скажите, какое-то время назад был один студент, он такой учебник, своим преподавателем писанный, демонстрировал - где этот способ навязывался как стандартный... :(

Comment: @Harry жуть какая.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int fun(int n, ...) {
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, n);

  int i = va_arg(args, int);

  va_end(args);

  return i;
}

int main() {
  printf("%d\n", fun(1, 10));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: да, такой метод тоже был на сайте, он следовал сразу после моего, поэтому решил начать по порядку)